# I cant add zebra to my Tables

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I use latex to create PDF for some academic journals and now I am using a Template to Layout articles. I have downloaded some templates and using them but I cant add none of zebra option to the tables. My document starts with following codes and packages:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Specify a different language here - english by default
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{multirow,color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
```

I wanted to use `[svgnames,table]{xcolor}` and `\rowcolors{5}{}{gray!10}` but latex shows me error and do not proceed to PDF, the error is `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`. I have created several documents and all of them works fine with rowcolors commands expect the document that starts with above codes.
Has anybody a suggestion that how can I add zebra to the tables in my document? or why LaTex shows me error every time? Is there any other way to add zebra style to the tables?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Can you please expand your code snippet to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228): that is, to a minimal chunk of *compilable* code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

This probably means your document class or some extension already loads `xcolor` with other options or none, whence the option clash.

You can either add  `svgnames` and `table` to the documentclass options, or write in the preamble

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, table}{xcolor}
```

B.t.w., needless to load `color`, nor `colortbl` if you load `xcolor` with option `[table]`, since it loads them for you.

Also (unrelated): the language options of `babel` should be loaded with the document class, and you don't have to declare these graphic extensions: they're already known to the graphic driver.

Comment: It's the normal behaviour. Or declare the options with the document class, as I said. The reason is that `chemformula` loads `tikz`, which loads `xcolor`.

Comment: Or `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` before `chemformula`...

Comment: Under the condition that `chemformula` (indirectly) loads it without option.